# How to find if a value exist within a Binary Tree: True or False (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, lookup

I am trying to write a code which the output returns either True or False, if the value exists within the Binary Tree.

Here is my attempt:

Defining a class called Node:

```
class Node:

def __init__(self, data):
    
    self.data = data
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
```

Defining a class called BinaryTree + LOOKUP function:

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, rootdata):
    self.root = Node(rootdata)

    def LOOKUP(self, lookupval):
        if lookupval < self.data:
            if (self.left == None):
                self.left.LOOKUP(lookupval)
                return False
        elif lookupval > self.data:
            if (self.right == None):
                self.right.LOOKUP(lookupval)
                return False
        else:
            return True
```

The rest, inputting values into the Binary Tree:

```
Tree = BinaryTree(24)
Tree.root.left = Node(11)
Tree.root.left.left = Node(199)
Tree.root.left.right = Node(167)
Tree.root.right = Node(2)
Tree.root.right.right = Node(8)

print(Tree.LOOKUP(11))
print(Tree.LOOKUP(13))
```

However, I keep getting the error `'BinaryTree' object has no attribute 'data'`..

I understand there will be some errors in the definition of the function LOOKUP,
but is there any chance that I could keep this format and still return the outputs:

```
True
False
```

Thank you,

Comment: Your should call `LOOKUP` like `Tree.LOOKUP(11, Tree.root)`. And then use `self.node.data/left/right` recursively.

Comment: Is the tree supposed to be a Binary Search Tree, or just an arbitrary binary tree, without any particular order? Because the logic of your `LOOKUP` method (to the extent it can be extracted around its issues) seems to be for a search tree, which needs to be in order if it is to function properly. And you're certainly not building an ordered tree.

Answer (score 1):

The issues in your code are:

- you're trying to reference `self.right` (should be `self.root.right` instead - because we're not on the `Node` instance)
- the nested if check are wrong. You should recursively check the left/right tree if **NOT** None or return False there.

Do something like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, rootdata):
        self.root = Node(rootdata)

    def LOOKUP(self, lookupval):
        
        if lookupval < self.root.data:
            if self.root.left: 
                return BinaryTree(self.root.left.data).LOOKUP(lookupval) # recursively check the left tree
            else:
                return False # can't go any further- so return false
        elif lookupval > self.root.data:
            if self.root.right:
                return BinaryTree(self.root.right.data).LOOKUP(lookupval)
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True

Tree = BinaryTree(24)
Tree.root.left = Node(11)
Tree.root.left.left = Node(199)
Tree.root.left.right = Node(167)
Tree.root.right = Node(2)
Tree.root.right.right = Node(8)

print(Tree.LOOKUP(11))
print(Tree.LOOKUP(13))
```

**output:**

```
True
False
```